# makefile, error compiling files from different paths

Tags: c++, makefile

I have 2 folders, the first folder contains the files I've built, and the second folder contains files I should be using without changing, all the files synchronize and work, already tested by manually compiling them while combined in 1 folder,

```sh
    CC:=g++
    COURSE_DIR:=/home/mtm/public/2122b/
    HW_DIR:=$(COURSE_DIR)ex2/
    OBJS=Card.o Player.o utilities.o Mtmchkin.o test.o
    EXEC=mtmchkin_test
    DEBUG_FLAG:=-g -DNDEBUG#assign -g for debug, or -DNDEBUG to turnoff assert
    HW_FLAG=-I -I$(HW_DIR)
    COMP_FLAG=--std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror $(HW_FLAG)
    
    $(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
            $(CC) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@
    Card.o : Card.cpp $(HW_DIR)Card.h Player.h $(HW_DIR)utilities.h
            $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.cpp -o $@
    Player.o : Player.cpp Player.h $(HW_DIR)utilities.h $(HW_DIR)Card.h
            $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.cpp -o $@
    utilities.o : $(HW_DIR)utilities.cpp $(HW_DIR)utilities.h
            $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.cpp -o $@
    Mtmchkin.o : Mtmchkin.cpp Mtmchkin.h $(HW_DIR)Card.h Player.h $(HW_DIR)utilities.h
            $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.cpp -o $@
    test.o : $(HW_DIR)test.cpp Player.h $(HW_DIR)Card.h Mtmchkin.h $(HW_DIR)utilities.h
            $(CC) -c $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(COMP_FLAG) $*.cpp -o $@
    clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

The makefile is in the first folder as I mentioned, and the `HW_DIR` is the path to the 2nd folder I mentioned, but it doesn't compile. Any idea on what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Edit:
This is the input I've made from the first folder i mentioned and contains the makefile and output

```sh
    [final]$ make
    g++ -c -g -DNDEBUG --std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -I -I/home/mtm/public/2122b/ex2/ Card.cpp -o Card.o
    Card.cpp:1:18: fatal error: Card.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Card.h"
                      ^
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [Card.o] Error 1
```

I want to it to compile successfully and put the exec file in the same folder as the makefile.

Comment: Have you verified that `$(COURSE_DIR)ex2/` actually contains a file named `Card.h`?

Comment: @Spencer yes, it contains all the files I've marked with $(HW_DIR), made sure of it

Comment: You define `HW_FLAG`, but you don't seem to use it anywhere.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it's expanded in the definition of `COMP_FLAG`

Comment: Please edit your question, using the Edit link, to add requested information so that the information can be formatted properly etc.  You can't format well in a comment.

Comment: @MadScientist You didn't notice OP's edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to be:

```
HW_FLAG=-I -I$(HW_DIR)
```

This sets the include path to `-I/home/mtm/public/2122b/ex2/` which (as a relative path, since it begins with `-`) would be a (presumably nonexistent) directory under the current directory.

it should be:

```
HW_FLAG=-I $(HW_DIR)
```

[GCC's command line documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) shows that `-I` can have a space before its argument.

Also, make sure that all of the different folders where your include files live are represented in the include path.  If (as it appears) there are `.h` files in the same folder as the makefile, you can try

```
 -I . -I $(HW_DIR)
```

However, you may need to specify the full path to the makefile instead of `.`

Finally, `$*` won't work for compiling `$(HW_DIR)utilities.cpp` and `$(HW_DIR)test.cpp` because they're in a different directory from the targets `utilities.o` and `test.o`. ([documentation link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)). Just use e.g. `$(HW_DIR)\utilities.cpp` explicitly for that rule, instead of `$*.cpp`.